# Vector-matrix-vector multiplication order?

Tags: linear-algebra

This is probably trivial but why is it true that:

$$y \bullet Ax = (A^Ty) \bullet x$$

Thanks!

Comment: Column space is the same as row space of transpose.

Answer (score 1):

Using that $u {\,\small\bullet\,} v = v^\textsf{T} u$ we have
$$y {\,\small\bullet\,} Ax = (Ax)^{\textsf T}y = x^\textsf{T}(A^{\textsf T}y) = (A^{\textsf T}y) {\,\small\bullet\,} x.$$